# Simultaneous updates to SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, locking, sql-update

I have a table will needs to be updated based on values within the table.  The whole table will be updated and I wanted to ensure that SQL-Server will handle the locking for me.  I know I can use `WITH(LOCKTYPE)`.  But as my update will be something like:

```
SELECT MyTable.ID, MyTable.Cost 
INTO #tempTable from MyTable

-- More complex calculations here

UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.Cost = #tempTable.Cost+1
FROM #tempTable
WHERE MyTable.ID = #TempTable.ID
```

I wanted to be sure that I could lock the entire table so that if another request comes in to update the table it has to wait, but ideally, if a read request comes in it is processed.  Is that possible?

### Edit

Process:

1. Read from Table X
2. Perform calculations
3. Write to temp table Y
4. Average values between X and Y
5. Write back to X

Within the SP, once step 1 has happened, I don't want any other calls to the SP to be processed, I want them to sit in a queue.  Because each update is dependent on the values already in the table, I cannot allow another call to the SP to read from the table.

In general, the SP needs to be run serially, the SP should not be allowed to be running twice at the same time.  I don't mind if the call goes through and the SELECT is queued, but once a select happens, another select (within the SP) cannot be allowed to happen in another thread.

Comment: are you looking to lock the table just for the update, or while you're doing the select and the calculations as well?  If just the update, SQL Server will handle that for you.  Also if possible specify which version of SQL server you're using.

Comment: As multiple updates could come in, I need to lock for the whole thing.  From the point that the values are read nothing can be allowed to change in the table (other requests must sit in the queue).  But things should still be able to read from the table.

Comment: This part will be a SP, but I need normal queries to still work (separately).  When this SP is called, if it is already running then it should wait... That's the general idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL transaction : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx#fbid=-CQjt8-slkk

Comment: Hi, what type of transaction would work?  Transactions by themselves don't force queuing, and from what I remember, they don't enforce queued writes.  Perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your problem but a transaction around all queries of your SP should maintains isolation of #temptable datas.
Perhaps I'm also wrong.